# ZedGraph C# помощь с графиком

Tags: c#, график, zedgraph

Есть график рисуется :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateStart", s1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFinish", s);
                MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                ds.Load(dr);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GraphPane mainPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
                mainPane.CurveList.Clear();
                PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
                PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
                    double x = (double)new XDate(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
                    double y = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
                    double y1 = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
                    list.Add(x, y);
                    list1.Add(x, y1);
                }
                LineItem CondensatCMC = mainPane.AddCurve("Конденсат ЦМЦ", list, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
                LineItem CondensatAuto = mainPane.AddCurve("Конденсат Автомойки", list1, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);
                mainPane.XAxis.ScaleFontSpec.Size = 10;
                mainPane.XAxis.Title = "Время";
                mainPane.YAxis.Title = "Проводимость";
                mainPane.Title = "График Конденсата";
                mainPane.XAxis.ScaleFormat = "HH:mm";
                mainPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
                mainPane.Legend.Position = LegendPos.Float;
                mainPane.Legend.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.PaneFraction;
                mainPane.YAxis.IsZeroLine = false;
                // Задаем выравнивание, относительно которого мы будем задавать координаты
                // В данном случае мы будем располагать легенду справа внизу
                mainPane.Legend.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Right;
                mainPane.Legend.Location.AlignV = AlignV.Bottom;

                // Включаем отображение сетки напротив крупных рисок по оси X
                mainPane.XAxis.IsVisible = true;
                mainPane.YAxis.IsVisible = true;
                mainPane.YAxis.IsVisible = true;
                // Задаем координаты легенды 
                // Вычитаем 0.02f, чтобы был небольшой зазор между осями и легендой
                mainPane.Legend.Location.TopLeft = new PointF(1.0f - 0.02f, 1.0f - 0.02f);
                mainPane.YAxis.MaxAuto = true;
                mainPane.XAxis.MaxAuto = true;

                zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
                zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
```

Проблема в том что не появляется сетка, хоть и выставил

```
                mainPane.XAxis.IsVisible = true;
                mainPane.YAxis.IsVisible = true;
                mainPane.YAxis.IsVisible = true;
```

и не могу понять как сделать что бы график рисовался с самого начала и до конца, и не было пустой области

[image: График]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примеры использования приведены здесь:
1) http://jenyay.net/ZedGraph/Grid – настройка сетки; 
2) http://jenyay.net/ZedGraph/Limit – настройка границ отображения интервала.

**О введении сетки**: Свойство "**MajorGrid**" появилось в **версии от 25.11.2005**. Если Вы пользуетесь более старой версией – нужно учесть, что для редактирования свойств отображения сетки может понадобиться обращаться к свойствам с пусть и похожими, но другими названиями.

**О настройке границ**: Не знаю, как *именно* получить число элементов списка вида "**PointPairList**" (написал как получение значения свойства "**.Count**"; *правка: как оказалось, тот список наследует свойство "**.Count**" от "**System.Collections.Generic.List**" – т.е. догадка правильная*) и как получить координату точки по оси абсцисс (написал как обращение к значению поля "**.x**"; *правка: оказалось, что имя данного свойства должно было писаться в верхнем регистре: "**.X**"*). Работоспособность проверена не была.

Код приведён с учётом исправлений (добавлено также отображение сетки по оси Y).

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateStart", s1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFinish", s);
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
ds.Load(dr);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
GraphPane mainPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
mainPane.CurveList.Clear();

PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();

/* Левая и правая граница интервалов: */
double xmin_limit, xmax_limit; // Вся область отображения
double xmin_plot1, xmax_plot1; // Первый график
double xmin_plot2, xmax_plot2; // Второй график

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
    double x = (double)new XDate(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
    double y = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
    double y1 = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
    list.Add(x, y);
    list1.Add(x, y1);
}

/* Определяем, который из двух графиков имеет "больший" интервал для отображения: 
* сперва -- для левой границы:
*/
xmin_plot1 = list[0].X;
xmin_plot2 = list1[0].X;
if (xmin_plot1 <= xmin_plot2) 
{
    xmin_limit = xmin_plot1;
} else 
{
    xmin_limit = xmin_plot2;
}

/* ... и, затем, для правой границы: */
xmax_plot1 = list[list.Count - 1].X;
xmax_plot2 = list1[list1.Count - 1].X;
if (xmax_plot1 >= xmax_plot2) 
{
    xmax_limit = xmax_plot1;
} else 
{
    xmax_limit = xmax_plot2;
}

LineItem CondensatCMC = mainPane.AddCurve("Конденсат ЦМЦ", list, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
LineItem CondensatAuto = mainPane.AddCurve("Конденсат Автомойки", list1, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);
mainPane.XAxis.ScaleFontSpec.Size = 10;
mainPane.XAxis.Title = "Время";
mainPane.YAxis.Title = "Проводимость";
mainPane.Title = "График Конденсата";
mainPane.XAxis.ScaleFormat = "HH:mm";
mainPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
mainPane.Legend.Position = LegendPos.Float;
mainPane.Legend.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.PaneFraction;
mainPane.YAxis.IsZeroLine = false;

// Задаём выравнивание, относительно которого мы будем задавать координаты
// (В данном случае, мы будем располагать легенду справа-внизу)
mainPane.Legend.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Right;
mainPane.Legend.Location.AlignV = AlignV.Bottom;

// Включаем отображение осей координат:
mainPane.XAxis.IsVisible = true;
mainPane.YAxis.IsVisible = true;

// Включаем отображение сетки напротив крупных рисок по оси X:
mainPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
mainPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.DashOn = 10;
mainPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.DashOff = 5;

// Включаем отображение сетки напротив крупных рисок по оси Y:
mainPane.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
mainPane.YAxis.MajorGrid.DashOn = 10;
mainPane.YAxis.MajorGrid.DashOff = 5;

// Устанавливаем интересующий нас интервал по оси X:
mainPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = xmin_limit;
mainPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = xmax_limit;

// Задаём координаты легенды: 
// (Вычитая 0.02f, чтобы был небольшой зазор между осями и легендой)
mainPane.Legend.Location.TopLeft = new PointF(1.0f - 0.02f, 1.0f - 0.02f);
mainPane.YAxis.MaxAuto = true;
mainPane.XAxis.MaxAuto = true;

zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
```